# How to simulate accelerometer events on Android wear emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, accelerometer, simulator, wear-os

I have started to develop a new app for Android Wear, but now that I want to use the accelerometer, I'm a little stuck.
Since I dont have an Android Wear devide, I have tried to use SensorSimulator for simulate accelerometer events but seems that it forces close after just a while.
Any ideas of how to da that?, 
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution?

Comment: Not yet, right now I'm just using the mobile app to test the accelerometer library I created.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I wasnt able and I have stoped trying it

Comment: Did you find a solution until now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set up an Android Wear device by installing android wear app available on google Play & then Follow the app instructions.
And also you can create your own project.
I think this is a good link that gives you better idea onCreating & Running Wearable App :-
(http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html)

Comment: My problem is not about simulating an Android Wear device, is about simulating the sensors for this emulator